# Keep two bash history files, one with ignoredups, one with everything

Tags: bash, command-history, bashrc

For the purposes of looking at which commands I am using the most, I'd like to keep a record of command I type in my bash history (even duplicates).

But, for sanity and ease of use, I still want to keep my ignoredups setting on.

Is there a way to automatically create two history files?  With the "default" being no duplicates, and the full history elsewhere?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could ignore the builtin history mechanism and abuse $PROMPT_COMMAND to write history any way you wanted. Some people keep a directory of history files, one for each shell/date/hostname, etc.  Approximately something like this:

```
prompt_cmd() {
    echo "$_" >> $HOME/.my_history_file_$HOSTNAME
}

PROMPT_COMMAND=prompt_cmd
```

obviously embellish with dates, times, whatever...

Comment: Nice, concise :)